# AngularJS fixed header scrollable table directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm stuck on a problem involving a fixed header table. I'm using AngularJS fixed header scrollable table directive to build table with fixed header. Once a search/filter term (field on top of the page) was entered and removed -> all TR rows don't fill up the hole page width (100%). Hint: TD width is set static by px values

I've put up a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vQ0a8Pvp69LCdpQPP5xo?p=preview).

**Directive code**

```
/**
 * AngularJS fixed header scrollable table directive
 * @author Jason Watmore <jason@pointblankdevelopment.com.au> (http://jasonwatmore.com)
 * @version 1.2.0
 */
(function () {
    angular
        .module('anguFixedHeaderTable', [])
        .directive('fixedHeader', fixedHeader);

    fixedHeader.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function fixedHeader($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        function link($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            var elem = $elem[0];

            // wait for data to load and then transform the table
            $scope.$watch(tableDataLoaded, function(isTableDataLoaded) {
                if (isTableDataLoaded) {
                    transformTable();
                }
            });

            function tableDataLoaded() {
                // first cell in the tbody exists when data is loaded but doesn't have a width
                // until after the table is transformed
                var firstCell = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:first-child');
                return firstCell && !firstCell.style.width;
            }

            function transformTable() {
                // reset display styles so column widths are correct when measured below
                angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('thead, tbody, tfoot')).css('display', '');

                // wrap in $timeout to give table a chance to finish rendering
                $timeout(function () {
                    // set widths of columns
                    angular.forEach(elem.querySelectorAll('tr:first-child th'), function (thElem, i) {

                        var tdElems = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                        var tfElems = elem.querySelector('tfoot tr:first-child td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');

                        var columnWidth = tdElems ? tdElems.offsetWidth : thElem.offsetWidth;
                        if (tdElems) {
                            tdElems.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        if (thElem) {
                            thElem.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        if (tfElems) {
                            tfElems.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                    });

                    // set css styles on thead and tbody
                    angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('thead, tfoot')).css('display', 'block');

                    angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('tbody')).css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        'height': $attrs.tableHeight || 'inherit',
                        'overflow': 'auto'
                    });

                    // reduce width of last column by width of scrollbar
                    var tbody = elem.querySelector('tbody');
                    var scrollBarWidth = tbody.offsetWidth - tbody.clientWidth;
                    if (scrollBarWidth > 0) {
                        // for some reason trimming the width by 2px lines everything up better
                        scrollBarWidth -= 2;
                        var lastColumn = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:last-child');
                        lastColumn.style.width = (lastColumn.offsetWidth - scrollBarWidth) + 'px';
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I think **fixed** is the wrong term here, if you want the header to stretch to the width of the tbody, then by **fixed** you mean **fit**

Comment: plus, I think your watch function is very unclear, as you return a boolean for the first argument, while it should be the name of an element of the scope to spy on.

Comment: Why not use angular https://github.com/alalonde/angular-scrollable-table ?

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did anyone find a solution? Looks like the plunker is still displaying the problem.